# How to add a while loop to this program in C++

Tags: c++, struct, while-loop

My program runs and is in correct format, but I am supposed to put the whole thing in a loop that allows the program to run through until the user enters 6 to quit. 1 is supposed to be subtracted from the drinks in the machine every time that the user buys. When sold out it will say "sold out". So the loop should repeat and display the total amount of money the machine earned.I don't know how to put the whole program into a while loop(im guessing) like this please help

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


struct Drink
{
    string drinkName;
    double cost;
    int numberInMachine;
};

struct Drink options[] = {{"Cola", .75, 0}, {"Root Beer", .75, 2},
                      {"Lemon-Lime", .75, 10},
                      {"Grape Soda", .80, 3}, {"Cream Soda", .80, 20}};

int getChoice();
double showTransaction(int);

int main()
{
    int choice;
    double moneyEarned = 0.0;

    choice = getChoice();
    moneyEarned = showTransaction(choice);

    cout <<"The machine earned: $" << moneyEarned << endl;


    //getChoice();
    //showTransaction(options, NUM_DRINKS, choice);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int getChoice()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "Enter the number(1-6) of the drink you would like: " << endl;
    cout << "Drink Name         Cost            " << endl; 
    cout << "1. Cola            .75             " << endl;
    cout << "2. Root Beer       .75             " << endl;
    cout << "3. Lemon-lime      .75             " << endl;
    cout << "4. Grape Soda      .80             " << endl;
    cout << "5. Cream Soda      .80             " << endl;
    cout << "6. Quit " << endl;

    cout << " Enter the number of your selection: ";
    cin >> choice;

    while(choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice !=3 && choice != 4 
                      && choice != 5 && choice != 6)
    {
            cout << "Please enter a valid number 1-6" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
    }

    return choice;
}
double showTransaction(int choice) 
{
    double moneyIn;

    if(options[choice - 1].numberInMachine < 1)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    cout << options[choice - 1].drinkName << "costs $" 
         << options[choice - 1].cost << endl;
    cout << "Enter money inserted up to $1.00: ";
    cin >> moneyIn;
    while(moneyIn < options[choice - 1].cost)
    {
        cout << "The money entered is not enough, please enter more: ";
        cin >> moneyIn;
    }
    cout << "Your change is: $" << (moneyIn - options[choice - 1].cost) 
                 << endl;

    return moneyIn;

}
```

Comment: You already have two `while` loops in the code you wrote - what don't you understand about how to add another?

Comment: There is no question here, its more like do my homework for me. Please tell us atleast what you have tried.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I dont understand how to put a while loop around the whole thing like to include the functions and whatnot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something along the line (some sketchy code):

```
for( ; ; ) {                      // infinite loop
    choice = getChoice();         // original code
    if( choice == 6 ) {
        break;                    // break out of loop and exit
    }
    moneyEarned = showTransaction(choice);        // original code
    if( moneyEarned < 0.01 ) {
        break;                    // break out of loop and exit
    }
}
```